# Crystal array of Strings declaration

Tags: arrays, declaration, crystal-lang

How do I declare an array of Strings in a getter / method declaration ?

Ex ( none of these exemples works ) :

```
class Test
    getter var1 : String[]
    getter var2 : String*
    getter var3 : Array(String)
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getter var3 : Array(String)
```

This is the correct way to declare an instance variable as an Array of String. However, you'll need to assign a value, either in the declaration or in the constructor.

If it should be an empty Array by Default, you can use

```
getter var3 = Array(String).new 
# or
getter var3 = [] of String
```

If you need the variable to allow a nil value, you can use

```
getter var3 : Array(String)?
```

Comment: Or `getter var3 = [] of String`

Comment: Added to the answer.